# Mongoose Deep Populate limiting intermediate model

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am using [MongooseDeepPopulate](https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate) package for the project. I have SchemaA, SchemaB, SchemaC, SchemaD. My SchemaD, SchemaC are connected to SchemaB and SchemaB is connected to SchemaA.

I have done like this.

```
var deepPopulate = require('mongoose-deep-populate')(mongoose);
AlbumSong.plugin(deepPopulate, {
    populate: {
        'song.category': {select: 'name status'},
        'song.poetId': {select: 'name status'}
    }
});
```

`song` is connection further with category and poetId. I am successfull with limiting fields from `category` and `poetId`. But I wish to limit fields from intermediate model `song` as well. My find query is like

```
AlbumSong.find(condition)
    .deepPopulate('song.category song.poetId')
//  .deepPopulate('song.category song.poetId' , '_id category poetId name nameHindi invalid status') // I tried this as well to limit records from song model as well.
    .exec(function(err, playlist) {
        callback(err, playlist);
    });
```

Where I have mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit the fields for the `AlbumSong`, you can just use the feature provided by [mongoose itself](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select), like this:

```
AlbumSong.find(condition)
   .select('_id category poetId name nameHindi invalid status')
   .deepPopulate(...)
```

[Here is](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/tree/master/nodejs-mongoose-deep-populate) a simple application to demonstrate the idea.
Schema looks like this:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  name:  String,
  email: String
});

var CommentSchema = new Schema({
  author  : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  title: String,
  body: String
})

var PostSchema = new Schema({
  title:  String,
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  comments: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'}],
  body:   String
});

PostSchema.plugin(deepPopulate, {
  populate: {
    'author': { select: 'name' },
    'comments': { select: 'title author' },
    'comments.author': { select: 'name' },
  }
});
```

The `deepPopulate` settings above limit fields for related `author`, `comments` and `comments.author`.
To get posts and limit fields for the post itself, I use this:

```
Post.find().select('title author comments').deepPopulate('author comments.author').exec(function(err, data) {
    // process the data
});
```

The data looks like this:

```
[{
    "_id": "56b74c9c60b11e201fc8563f",
    "author": {
        "_id": "56b74c9b60b11e201fc8563d",
        "name": "Tester"
    },
    "title": "test",
    "comments": [
        {
            "_id": "56b74c9c60b11e201fc85640",
            "title": "comment1",
            "author": {
                "_id": "56b74c9b60b11e201fc8563e",
                "name": "Poster"
            }
        }
    ]
}]
```

So for the post itself we only have `title` (`body` is not selected).
For populated records the selected fields are limited as well.